# Moshi - Unable to create converter for enum class for gradle 8 and upwards

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, moshi

An error occurs during runtime, after updating to gradle 8.1.1 from 7.4.2: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class $myEnumClass Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.reflect.Field java.lang.Class.getField(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference". I use EnumJsonAdapterFactory to parse enums that is declared on this way when creating moshi:
`val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(EnumJsonAdapterFactory).build()`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: I found this solution and I post it in order to help everyone who faces the same problem.
When using EnumJsonAdapterFactory for parsing enums, you must add
 `-keep class your.package.name.EnumIntSafeJsonAdapter { *; }`
 in proguard-rules.pro of app's build.gradle. This error caused by the fact that android.enableR8.fullMode is enabled by default in gradle 8 and upwards